# WPF Listview Scrollbar Visibility Trigger

Tags: wpf, triggers

I'm trying to set up a trigger that removes the padding on the listview when the scrollbar is hidden.

I put the trigger on the listview style but I'm getting inconsistent results. For example the background property in the trigger is always active no matter what the scrollbar visibility is.

I've taken a look at the MSDN for the [ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.computedverticalscrollbarvisibility?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_ScrollViewer_ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility)  but am not having much luck figuring out what's wrong.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" Margin="5"
          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- SNIP -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="ListView.Padding" Value="0,0,5,0"/>
            <Setter Property="ListView.Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden">
                    <Setter Property="ListView.Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="ListView.Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Style>
</ListView>
```

Comment: First of all Property="ListView.Padding" remove ListView from properties name. Just like this: <Style TargetType="ListView"><Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,5,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="..." /></Style>

Comment: @PéterHidvégi If I do that Visual Studio throws an error saying the property isn't recognizable or accessable. I find that when writing styles inside controls I often have to prefix the property with the control type.

Comment: i don't think so... Did you try to set TargetType of the Style?

Comment: Setting the target type does indeed remove the need for the control prefixes but it doesn't solve the real problem I'm having. Thanks for that bit of info though.

Comment: @Andronomos That's because you're looking at the wrong element. You need to look at the actual ScrollViewer, not the ListView itself.  You can't get to the scrollviewer the way you have it now... you'd have to dump out the full style and do it in there... it's pretty small... not a big deal.

Comment: @SledgeHammer That makes sense and I was thinking that might be the issue but I wasn't sure how to correctly target it without completely re writing the template. I guess there isn't a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write an ListView style example which worked for me. I tried it.

```
<Style TargetType="ListView">
      <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
      <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                          <ScrollViewer>
                                 <ScrollViewer.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                                       <Style.Triggers>
                                             <Trigger Property="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible">
                                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="100"/>
                                              </Trigger>
                                              <Trigger Property="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Collapsed">
                                                  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10"/>
                                              </Trigger>
                                       </Style.Triggers>
                                     </Style>
                                 </ScrollViewer.Style>
                             <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                 </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
 </Style>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was hoping I could get it to work without needing to modify the listview's template because I didn't want it to interfer with the listview's ItemContainerStyle and ItemTemplate but it seems to work just fine.